# How do I beat stage 1-4 in Donkey Kong for Game Boy?

Tags: donkey-kong-94

I am on stage 1-4 of Donkey Kong for the Game Boy and can't figure out how to progress. Donkey Kong is dropping debris on my head and I can't see a way to reach him. There are platforms above me but no ladders I can climb up. Trying to jump on top of the falling debris just kills me.

How do I beat Stage 1-4 in Donkey Kong for the Game Boy?

[image: Stage 1-4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an offscreen ladder to the left you can climb to reach Donkey Kong.

Keep walking left until the screen starts scrolling to reveal an off-screen ladder you can use to climb up. Once you're up, climb down the ladder to the right, jump across the platforms, climb back up, and make your way to Pauline to beat the level.

[image: Screen scrolled to show ladder]

Video demonstration